# How to understand why I keep getting: ssh-copy-id Permission denied (publickey)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up my production Rails server using Ubuntu Server 14.04 that I launched from Amazon EC2. This is not the first time I have ever done this, and many times in the past have been successful.

The problem is that almost every single time I try to use `ssh-copy-id` to copy my `.pub` file when I am setting up the instance, it fails about 95% of the time with `Permission denied (publickey).`.

I really don't know why this *always* happens. I have attempted various solutions that I've read in countless other SO questions and answers, and those never work either. Most SO answers suggest that `ssh-copy-id` *is* the solution to the problem, but for me it always ends up being the other way around.

Here are some of the solutions I've tried:

1. Setting `PasswordAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Setting `RSAAuthenication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
3. Setting `PubkeyAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
4. Uncommenting `AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
5. Pubbing out the `.pem` I downloaded from EC2 to a `.pub` using openssl and then trying to `ssh-copy-id` it to the server

   - *e.g. `openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/mykey.pem -pubout > ~/.ssh/mykey.pub`*
   - *followed by: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pub ubuntu@[IPADDRESS]*
6. Generating my own key with `ssh-keygen` and trying `ssh-copy-id`.

I should note that I have forgotten how I've gotten past the same hurdles with my last setups, because I remember that each time I fixed it in the past, the solutions were wildly different from each other, like doing a `bundle update` for `net-ssh` gem one time around and then pubbing out the pem another time for another but had to do it for the root user instead of the originally intended user, blah blah blah.

I think the problem here, too, is that I am not fully understanding how ssh keys work. I know I download the `mykey.pem`. And then I restrict access to the `.pem` using `sudo chmod 400 /path/to/mykey.pem` because it needs to be protected. And then I can use `ssh -i /path/to/mykey.pem ubuntu@[ipaddress]` to ssh in. From there, everything else seems to be unclear.

What is the simplest process to connecting my local machine to my production server with ssh keys? How can I use `ssh-copy-id` to get allow my local machine to do so?

Answer (score 1):

> followed by: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pub ubuntu@[IPADDRESS]`

This is nonsense. `-i` accepts private key part.

If you downloaded PEM key from EC2, and the public part is on the server, you should be able to connect to the instance using

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem ubuntu@[IPADDRESS]
```

If it does not work, check the server log `/var/log/auth.log` for errors. `ssh-copy-id` requires from you to have also password-based access to the server, which is not allowed in EC instances, if I am right (for that the errors).

If the above does not work, create new key using `ssh-keygen -f new_key`, and copy the public part from `new_key.pub` to server file `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` as a text and then connect like `ssh -i new_key ubuntu@[IPADDRESS]`.

If you want to connect with `ssh alias`, provide the `ssh_config` in `~/.ssh/config` such as:

```
Host alias
  Hostname [IPADDRESS]
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile your_key
```

Comment: When using `ssh-copy-id` the argument for `-i` has to be a `.pub` file. When I try with a `.pem` file it fails. That's true though about it creates the key on the server when I create the EC2 instance. How can i ssh in by just using `ssh ubuntu@[ipaddress]` instead of `ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem ubuntu@[IPADDRESS]`? The latter works, but the first fails with Permission denied. I think thats why my capistrano fails to ssh in when I try to upload to production.

Comment: For this, there is `ssh_config` and option, `IdentityFile`. Use the Google, Luke (and I edited the answer).